# How can I compile all invalid obects in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to write a PL/SQL procedure that finds all invalid objects, order in hierarchical manner (supertype ---> subtype) and than compile them.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql` script for this?

Answer (score 8):

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(schema => '<your schema>', compile_all => FALSE, reuse_settings => TRUE);
END;
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73226

Answer (score 0):

To find all invalid objects:

```
select * from dba_objects obj where status = 'INVALID'
```

To find dependencies of an object:

```
select * from dba_dependencies where owner = 'xxx' and name = 'yyy'
```

To compile an object:

```
alter procedure user.procedure_name
compile
```

I'm not pretty sure how you can order according to hierarchy, I'll think about it. Meanwhile maybe you can come up with a solution by using these tools. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will be very happy if you find a solution to the ordering problem.